Suppose $f(g(x)) = e^{2 \ln x-2}$ and $g(f(x)) = 2x − 1$. Find possible formulas for $f$ and $g$. [Hint: recall that $\ln(e^u)=u$]
I have been stuck on this question for a while now.
I know how composition of functions works but do not understand how to find the functions given the two of them composed together. I have simplified $f(g(x))$ to equal $\frac{x^2}{e^2}$. However, I am not sure where to go to find $f$ and $g$. Please answer as soon as possible because this assignment is due tomorrow.

Please use Latex to format your questions.

Based on the forms of $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$, it makes sense to suppose that $g$ is a logarithmic function and $f$ is an exponential function.
If we let $f(x)=e^{2x}$ and $g(x)=\ln x-1$, then we get that: $$f(g(x))=e^{2(\ln x-1)}=e^{2 \ln x-2}$$ $$g(f(x))=\ln(e^{2x})-1=2x-1$$ as required.

Oh yeah. I guess I need to look more into the factoring bit for the exponents.
